# Arfaly Progress bar (How To)

Tags: php, progress-bar

I am having this arfaly upload script and it works awesome, but the problem is there is no progress bar, i was searching on google but there is nothing about arfaly progress bars, and i was thinking is there any way to add it.  Here is the code for upload (HTML)

```html
<div id="mas" class="arfaly-multiple-upload">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="itech_mass_upload_submission">
  <div>
    <div id="arfaly-filedrag" style="color: rgb(119, 119, 119); border: 0px dashed rgb(119, 119, 119); min-width: 100%; display: block;">
      <span class="arfaly-showcase icon icon-cloud-storage" style="color:#5e5e5e"></span>
      <br>Drag &amp; Drop files or Click</div>
      <input type="file" style="display:none" name="files[]" id="mas-arfaly-files" multiple="">
      <br></div><div id="mas-ListItem" class="arfaly-multi-images">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I found jquery progress bar, but it doest work, this is not form

Comment: *"i was searching on google but there is nothing about arfaly progress bars"* - I beg to differ. Keep looking.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is nothing even on their main page, and i am searching and searching but still nothing.